# primefaces <p:layout> not working with IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm facing a problem when using IE to browse http://gamma.j.layershift.co.uk

My site is built using JSF2 with primefaces 3.5.

**the rest of page can seen on Firefox and chrome.

the problem happened only on the index(first) page.

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/template.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<ui:define name="content">
    <!-- p:galleria panelWidth="960" panelHeight="350"
        value="#{mbIndex.img}" var="image" styleClass="ui-corner-all">
        <p:graphicImage id="gal_image" value="resources/images/#{image}" />
    </p:galleria -->

    <p:imageSwitch effect="fade" speed="2900" styleClass="center"
        style="width:1000px;height:400px;">
        <ui:repeat value="#{mbIndex.img}" var="image">
            <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/#{image}"
                style="clip:rect(0px, 1000px, 400px, 0px);min-width:1000px; min-height:400px;" />
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:imageSwitch>

    <br />

    <p:layout style="max-height:500px !important;">
        <p:layoutUnit position="west" header="About GAMMA"
            style="max-width:300px !important; height:300px; !important">
            <h:outputLabel style="word-wrap: break-word;"
                value="The company started in 2012 focusing on the production of disinfectants. Our products are used in laboratories, clean rooms, and process areas in pharmaceutical, biotechnology, healthcare, academic and industrial facilities in addition to livestock animals, " />
            <p:commandLink value="More info..." action="#{mbIndex.toAbout}"></p:commandLink>

    </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="center" header="Latest news">

        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Any explanation please?
Thanks.

This screenshot from Firefox (what the page should be).
[image: This screenshot from Firefox]

--When using IE just the image shown.

Comment: please add an attachment showing what is wrong with the page under IE and what is the desired result: 1) not everyone that can help you has IE 2) "picture tells a thousand words"

Comment: Thanks. I post a link to the desired result.

Comment: yeah, but the more important is the screenshot from IE ;)

Comment: now i really can't...
Maximum is 2 links for now..

Comment: Here is the problem when using IE9, there is no <P:layout>... http://i.stack.imgur.com/gLxtH.jpg

Answer (score 7):

The below worked for me in IE 9, i had this in my css.

```
.ui-layout-container {
    overflow-x:visible !important; overflow-y:visible !important;
}
```

Comment: This is great because it works, but should not this be fixed in primefaces?

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is a CSS issue.

Modify css class ui-layout-container or set style attribute and change the overflow attributes to:

```
<p:layout style="max-height:500px !important; overflow-x:visible !important; overflow-y:visible !important;">
```

This worked for me in IE8 and should work in IE9 too.

Comment: Ok that´s strange. I tried to edit the CSS Values with the IE Debugger (F12). The CSS Attributes overflow-x and overflow-y were set to hidden. After changing them to visible, the layout panels were shown correctly...

Comment: Any idea why primefaces sets overflow-x & y to hidden ?